# Homeomorphism between Kronecker product $U(N)\otimes U(k)$ and a direct product of Lie groups

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, topological-groups

I am considering the space $A$ consisting of the Kronecker product: 
\begin{eqnarray}
A=\{U(N)\otimes U(k)\}, 
\end{eqnarray}
where $U(N)$ is the $N$ by $N$ unitary matrices and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product of matrices.

My question is whether we can find a homeomorphism between $A$ and some direct product of Lie group in the form as
\begin{eqnarray}
U(1)\times\cdots\times U(1)\times SU(N)\times SU(k). 
\end{eqnarray}
Here, to distinguish from Kronecker product $\otimes$, we use $\times$ to denote the direct product of groups.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) is the same thing as the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), represented relative to a basis?

But in general tensor product is something we do to linear spaces, not Lie groups. So I don't really have an answer to your question, except to say that it doesn't seem like a very natural question. Consider this perhaps an extended comment instead of an attempted answer.

However remember that $U(n)$ is defined as a set of matrices which preserve some hermitian form on a vector space. It definitely makes sense to take tensor products of those vector spaces, and see how the matrices act on the resulting space. The decomposition is a little involved, going under the name of [Clebsch-Gordon coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and actually my motivation to do it is the fundamental homotopy group of A. If I can do that direct product decomposition of Lie group, the homotopy group generator is easily seen.